# Rails skip before action doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i've some problem with the skip_before action:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :require_login
  before_action :inc_cookies

  def inc_cookies
    if cookies[:token] != nil
      @name = cookies[:name]
      @surname = cookies[:surname]
      @user_roomate = cookies[:roomate]
    end
  end

  def require_login
    if cookies[:token] == nil
      puts "No token"
      redirect_to '/'
    end


  end
end
```

and my other controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_action :require_login, :except => [:landing, :connect, :create]
end
```

I don't know why, but when I'm on the root (the :landing action from UsersController), Rails try to pass in the require_login...
I've misundertood something with this filter, or do I something wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This sounds normal to me - you've asked rails to skip your before action, except if the action is `:landing`, `:connect` or `:create` whereas it sounds as though you want the opposite. If you want those 3 actions not to execute the `require_login` then you should be doing

```
skip_before_action :require_login, :only => [:landing, :connect, :create]
```

Comment: Ok, I'm definitly stupid, I've forgot than the "skip", should do the contrary of before_action... Thanks :)