# Rails Skip Before Filter on API Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, skip, before-filter

Is there any way to skip the before filter for an action when an API call is being made?

So generally I want before_filter x to be executed EXCEPT when I'm doing an API call.

```
skip_before_filter :x, :except => API CALL BEING MADE
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends a little in how you define an API call. If it's any request with a JSON format you could do something like this:

```
skip_before_action :x if: -> { request.format.json? }
```

This doesn't seem to be an ideal solution though, and it might be better to make separate controllers for Web and API. You might do something along these lines:

```
class APIController < ApplicationController
     # API-specific filters
end

class SomeOtherController < APIController
    # your API actions
end
```

And you'd do the same for web, then configure your routes to take the request to the correct controller action.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can add

```
    skip_before_action :x, only: WHEN API CALL BEING MADE
```

I guess, you would want `only` and not `except`

Comment: you're right - sloppy error on my part. but the real question was with what comes after the only/except

Comment: you need to put the name of the action, which is handling the API call. Have  a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204055/rails-skip-before-action-doesnt-work) , which has a similar question

Comment: i want it for every call made by API

Comment: your API calls would be routed to certain actions in your controller, isn't it. you can mention ` skip_before_action :x, only: [:action1, :action2, :action3]`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but the fact that you want different behaviors for API and web requests might be a smell that your API requests could be handled by a separate controller (I'm sure there are differences in the responses you are sending as well). The code will probably be cleaner with less branching inside controllers. You could even have both controllers inherit from a "Base" controller that does common queries to eliminate duplication.

Anyway, `except` and `only` can only accept names of controller actions, so in your callback method you could consider branching on `request.headers["Content-Type"] == 'application/json` or `request.xhr?`